# Some checkboxes work and other don't- why?

Tags: html, django, checkbox, django-templates

In my Django project, I have one page that displays a list of items and a checkbox next to each item. For some reason, some of the checkboxes are not 'checkable'. I can't tell why this behavior changes because most of the checkboxes work fine. Why would some checkboxes work but not others, when I'm displaying them all the same way?

snippet from mypage.html:

```
<form method="get" action="next_step">
    {% for item in myitems %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="yourselection" value="{{item.id}}"> Item info goes here
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: Could it be a simple CSS problem? I have had a similar problem in the past where an invisible overlaying div was preventing me from clicking on form elements.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much @NicoleHarris It was hard to find but I got it!